# how can I include condition inside parallel in Jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

For example I have following job and I would like to put condition using when, right now it doesn't allow me to put when inside parallel, I only want to run testusers if bool is true

```
                      dir("abc") {

                              parallel (users: {
                              sh "add_user users.json"
                              },
                              when{ ${TEST_USERS} == "true" }
                              testusers: {
                              sh "add_user testusers.json"
                              })

                          }
                       }
                    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`when` blocks only operate on stages, so something like:

```
parallel {
    stage('testusers') {
        when {
            environment name: 'TEST_USERS', value: 'true'
        }
        steps {
            sh "add_user testusers.json"
        }
    stage('users') {
        steps {
            sh "add_user users.json"
        }
    }
}
```

---

In scripted, you would just use an `if` block. This looks like:

```
parallel ([
    'users': {
        sh 'add_user users.json'
    },
    'testusers': {
        if (TEST_USERS == 'true') {
            sh 'add_user testusers.json'
        }
    }
])
```